# How can I debug when a cron job isn't executed in a certain docker container?

Tags: docker, cron, centos

What I have done is:

```
docker run --rm -it SomeCentOsBasedImage   
(in a docker container)   
yum update -y   
yum install -y vim cronie python3   
vim /script.sh   
   #!/bin/bash   
   echo "a" >> /target.txt   
chmod 777 script.sh   
crontab -e   
   * * * * * /script.sh   
crond -n
```

But this doesn't work.

The `target.txt` file isn't generated.

I checked `crontab -l`, and it showed `* * * * * /script.sh`.

When I do the exact same operations in `docker run --rm -it centos:7` container, `target.txt` file is generated properly.

I have to debug this problem, but all I can do is just checking `crontab -l`.

What else can I do for this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Where are you checking the `target.txt`? Inside the container or on host machine?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Except for the first line(`docker run --rm -it Image`), all the operations are done in a container. That `script.sh` file is to generate and edit a file in a container, of course. Those indented lines should be typed in the above file.

Comment: Put your complete dockerfile here

Comment: @TarunLalwani This doesn't have to do with Dockerfile. I just ran an image without a Dockerfile, entered into the container, and tried to do a cron job.

Comment: So you are saying that it has in issue with your CentOS based image but not in Centos image ?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes. Strictly, not my image, but I pulled the image from a private repository. That 'bad image' is based on centos:7. When I do the same with centos:7 image, everything goes well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213836/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-yoon).